# How to make a button component in react functional hooks, which can accept input as well as plus/minus button values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a react button component which is having plus & minus buttons along with an input option to insert the required Quantity. I want the input to work with the plus & minus buttons. Finally i have an Add Button & when i click Add button, it should get updated in the Cart.

The problem's i'm facing are :

1. The input is not working as expected. I'm unable to correct back or enter input.
2. I don't want to show 0 in the input field, but if i `setCount("");` it will make the initial state blank & the plus button will not work as require.
3. How to display/include handle plus & minus Error messages in the `handleValueChange()`.
4. I want the code to be Refactored to have only a minimum no of lines as possible and should be able to understand it (not condensed).

I Greatly appreciate for any additional code added for its improvement.

Link to Sandbox -- [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/qtbutton-kgc4x?file=/src/components/App/Qbutton.jsx)

It will be very helpful if i can refer to a working sandbox if possible.

My Code as below:

//App.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Qbutton from "./Qbutton";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>          
      <Qbutton />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

//QuantityButton.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Qbutton(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const Qty = 12;

  function handlePlus() {
    if (count < Qty) {
      setCount(count + 1);
      setError(null);
    } else {
      setError("No stock");
    }
  }

  function handleMinus() {
    if (count > 0) {
      setCount(count - 1);
      setError(null);
    } else {
      setError("No items in Cart");
    }
  }

  function handleValueChange(e) {
    const x = Number(e.target.value);
        
    if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > Qty) {
      setError(
        "Input not valid"
      ); /*How to display/include handle plus & minus Error messages*/
    } else {
      setCount(x);
      setError("Qty updated");
    }
    console.log(x);
  }

  function SubmitQty(e) {
    setError("Items Added to Cart");        
    setCount(0);
    /* Delete setCount if u want the selected Quantity to show up.. Set it "0" if required it to get cleared*/
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  console.log(count);
  return (
    <div className="btnWrapper">
      <h1> Quantity Button </h1>

      <div className="counterDisplay">
        <button
          style={{ borderRadius: "25px 0px 0px 25px" }}
          onClick={handleMinus}
        >
          -
        </button>
        <input
          type="text"
          min="0"
          value={count}
          onClick={() => setCount(0)}
          onChange={handleValueChange}
        />
        <button onClick={handlePlus}>+</button>
        <button
          className="AddBtn"
          style={{ borderRadius: "0px 25px 25px 0px" }}
          onClick={SubmitQty}
        >
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
      {error}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Qbutton;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
App.js

import React, { useState } from "react";

import Qbutton from "./Qbutton";

function App() {
  // U should map the Qty in Qbutton.
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  function addItem(newItem) {
    console.log(newItem , "New Itemm")
    setCart((prevNotes) => {
      return [newItem];
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Items in Cart: {cart + ""} </h1>
      <Qbutton onAdd={addItem} qty={6} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;






QtButton.js

import React, { useState } from "react";

function Qbutton(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  function handlePlus() {
    if(count === null || count === ""){
      setCount(1);
    } else {
      setCount(count + 1);
      setError(null);
    }
  }

  function handleMinus() {
    if (count > 0) {
      setCount(count - 1);
      setError(null);
    } else {
      setError("Please Enter a Valid Number");
    }
  }

  function handleValueChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
    if (e.target.value === "" || re.test(e.target.value)) {
      const x = Number(e.target.value);
      setCount(x);
      setError("Qty updated");
    } else {
      setError("Your input is not valid");
    }
  }

  function SubmitQty(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (count !== 0 && count !== null) {
      props.onAdd(count);
      setError("Items Added to Cart");
      setCount("");
    } else {
      setError("Please Enter a Valid Number");
    }
    /* Delete setCount if u want the selected Quantity to show up.. Set it "0" 
      if required it to get cleared*/
  }

  return (
    <div className="btnWrapper">
      <h1> Quantity Button </h1>

      <div className="counterDisplay">
        <button
          style={{ borderRadius: "25px 0px 0px 25px" }}
          onClick={handleMinus}
        >
          -
        </button>
        <input
          type="text"
          min="0"
          value={count}
          onClick={() => setCount(null)}
          onChange={handleValueChange}
        />
        <button onClick={handlePlus}>+</button>
        <button
          className="AddBtn"
          style={{ borderRadius: "0px 25px 25px 0px" }}
          onClick={SubmitQty}
        >
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
      {error}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Qbutton;
```

Comment: Hi Kaliraj, Thank you for your time to have a look on my code. When i key in 1 inside the input and then add it; It adds to the cart, but after doing it if i press + button, it will increment 1, 11, 111 and so on. And i do need the "No stock" message if the Qty is less.

Comment: @BhushanNayak Please check the above code, increment 1, 11, 111 and so on is already fixed and there is no "No stock message" on the code. i hope this will resolved some of your problems.

Comment: Ok.. see we are setting the setCount(null) inside the input onClick. . so when we press the increment button it has to increment a null.. which gives an error.. to analyse, just key in some number then press Add. now without keying in anything just press the increment button twice.. it will show u what i'm trying to clarify. You can see this link to check your answer ... https://codesandbox.io/s/qtbutton-forked-uhhrs?file=/src/components/App/Qbutton.jsx

Comment: @BhushanNayak Please check the above code now, I made some edit.Hope it helps you